# shutter speed is not consistent on analog camera

Tags: film, repair, minolta

I'm very new to analog photography so I'm not very familiar with all the terms.

Just this month I bought my first analog camera, a Minolta XD-7. It was sold as fully functional but when it arrived that wasn't the case. I've already managed to repair some electronic problems, but now the shutter speed (meaning the times like 1/1000, 1/500, 1/250) are not consistent. It seems like sometimes it gets stuck and takes a while longer, sometimes it functions well (at least in my opinion)

I already found this [service manual](https://www.suaudeau.eu/memo/manuels_rep/reflexes/minolta/minolta_xd_repair_guide.pdf) but I really don't know where to look. I don't want to do something without knowing that it is definitely going to help.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Sometimes mechanical shutters can get stuck a bit if the camera is left unused for a long time. _Sometimes_ you just need to "exercise" the shutter a bit, to bring it back to a good working order. But... it's a delicate mechanism, so I'd advise rather taking your camera to a good local camera shop and ask for their advice there.

Comment: Sounds like it needs a CLA (clean, lube, adjust) at least. It might need repair as well.

Comment: It is an old camera and who knows it’s history? Beyond that the previous  owner said it worked when it didn’t.

Comment: @osullic yeah i heard that too. Ive been trying to use it everyday without film for some minutes. Maybe it starts to sound better but sometimes it still takes longer than usual. Im just scared of the costs if i take it to a shop. I already talked to one and they wanted 50€ for just a look at the camera to determine whats wrong and maybe more.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens and how do i do that? Maybe if you look at the service manual you could help me with that

Comment: The internet can provide information like the service manual. The internet can make finding a repair shop easier. But the internet can’t fix a camera because the internet can’t turn screwdrivers and squeeze tweezers. There is a camera repair course at https://learncamerarepair.com/ and a Facebook group.

Comment: thats true, maybe i expected too much. I just feel a bit lost and i think if i had more information i could fix this problem. Sadly i dont know much about cameras, at all. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Well, now you know to look at the "shutter" section of the service manual. Look through that part for trouble shooting steps and, when you seem to have the problem identified as best you can, execute the "problem resolution" steps recommended. Also, I'm curious how you're timing the shutter to know that it's not right. You say it's inconsistent, but if it were perfectly consistent, would it be at exactly 1/1000? How would you know?

Comment: Just sometimes with the same settings the "click" takes longer (maybe a second when it should be 1/50 of a second) and sometimes it is shorter. Since i dont know much about the subject its kinda hard to explain. The repair manual doesnt really have a subcategory for this type of problem. I guess i will really take it to a repair shop